# Dynamically loading Python application code from database under Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to store python code in a database and load it in some kind of bootstrap.py application for execution. I cannot use filesystem because I'm using GAE, so this is my only choice.

However I'm not a python experienced user.

I already was able to load 1 line of code and run it using eval, however a piece of code with two lines or more gave me a "invalid syntax" error.

I'm also thinking if it's possible to extend the "import" loader to implement the DB loading.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, but extending import does sound pretty creative.

Comment: If GAE allows you to override `import`, I'd be surprised. Why script code in a database? Since you claim to be not experienced with Python, there is probably a much better way to do what you want. What are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to create a App that has the option to be updated "automatically" without using GAE SDK.

Comment: Ooh self-morphing code. What a horrible idea. Have you looked at GAE's application versioning?

Comment: That's not the point. I want to make an app that can be used and updated by non-programmers.

Comment: If the app changes are made by non-programmers, how does code get stored in the DB?

Comment: ... without having to download and install some kind of SDK for future updates.

Comment: So you didn't look at application versioning. http://appengine.google.com/deployment?&app_id=your_app_id

Comment: This is probably a terrible idea. But you _can_ override import in App Engine.

Comment: Versioning isn't helpful for what he wants to do

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do what I intent after reading more about Python dynamic code loading.

Here is the sample code. I removed headers to be lighter:

Thanks anyway!

=============

```
class DynCode(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    code = db.TextProperty(default=None)
```

=============

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        dyn = DynCode()
        dyn = "index"
        dyn.code = """
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("Hello World\\n")
        self.response.out.write("Hello World 2\\n")
"""
        dyn.put()
        self.response.out.write("OK.")

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/update', MainHandler)], debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

==================================

```
def main():
    query = DynCode.all()
    dyncodes = query.fetch(1)
    module = imp.new_module('mymodule')
    for dyn in dyncodes:
        exec dyn.code in module.__dict__

    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', module.MainHandler)], debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

=======================

Comment: So how does the `DynCode` get loaded? How does `dyn.code` get tested? What state is the application in if there is a syntax error in `dyn.code`?

Comment: DynCode is a simple file imported in the last one. The testing I will do in a separate place. There is no difference of loading a syntax broken code from a separate file or loading it from a string.

Comment: Very interesting. @HGF are you still using this code after 3 years? I am interested to do something similar.

Comment: Hi @erasmospunk. The code worked at that time. I've stopped this project so I don't know if it still works.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a more robust mechanism, you probably want to read [PEP302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/), which describes input hooks. You can use these to import code rather than having to eval it.

Answer (score 2):

I somewhat agree with the commentators above, it sounds kind of dangerous. However:

I experimented a little with App Engine Console ( http://con.appspot.com/console/ ), and `eval()` indeed tended to throw `SyntaxError`'s.

Instead, the `exec` statement might be your friend ( http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/exec.html ).

I managed to run this in App Engine Console:

```
>>> exec "def f(x):\n    x = x + 1\n    y = 10\n    return x + y"
>>> f(10)
21
```

So try the `exec` statement, but remember the many, many (many!) perils of code coming directly from end-users.

Comment: Thank you. I already solved my problem. I think I got misunderstood on the problem. My intent is to enable the application to be self updated when needed instead of asking the user to download GAE SDK to updated the application after installed. I'll post my implementation here.

Comment: However, why do you think this may be dangerous?

Comment: This would be dangerous if the code above came from end-users, it exposes your app to attacks and/or stupidity. Even if the user group is very controlled, you never know.

Comment: Ok. This is a controlled environment. Code in DB will only be replaced by the app itself, and will probably be downloaded from a single thrusted source.