# google app engine file upload

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload

I would like to be able to upload a file to a folder under the same directory of my python script, much of the same way that one would with php. I tried using blobstore but the file did not appear in the same directory as my files (or if it did, I did not see it) which is a must for my application.

So, how can I upload a file to a folder in a folder, that is in the same directory as my python scripts.

Answer (score 2):

GAE file system is read-only you can not write to it. The files can only be changed via project update process (`appcfg`).

So what you are attempting to do is not possible.

If you are looking for a way to dynamically upload python code and execute it, then yes this is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3506164/248432