# Executing python against a script stored in database

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python-2.7

- db: mysql
- lang: python
- framework:
- django
- Operating System: Linux (ubuntu)

Hello,

Is there a way to execute a python against a content of a script that is stored in a database?  For example, a content of a file is stored in a db column text.  Would the only solution be to create a temporary file, dump the content from the db into the file and then run python os command against it?  I'm assuming the content of the executed script will need to be stored such that it escapes quotes etc.

I'm open to suggestions on what database to use to accomplish my goal.  MySQL will require additional wrappers before storage of the file content and possibly apply others to reply qoutes/datetime/etc.

Please advise if additional information necessary, but in essence i'm looking to store python script content in a db, retrieve it and run it against the python interpreter.

Thank you in advance for any advise.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `compile` built in function.

```
s = """def f(x):
    return x + x

print(f(22))
"""

code = compile(s, "string", "exec")

exec(code)
# OUT: 44
```

Although I'm wondering if you couldn't just store a data structure and use that with some pre-defined code. Executing arbitrary code in this way could be dangerous, and a security risk.

Comment: Hi Keith, thanks for your reply.  I'm not sure I understand what you mean by pre-defined code, could you explain?  The code would not arbitrary, but you do bring up a good point, it would leave the system vulnerable.

Comment: Meaning that you write some code that reands in and validates the data. I'm not sure what your application is, but I suspect that what you really need is just some data in your... database.

Comment: Sweet. Yes the validation will be done, thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

This seems very similar to SO post here:

[Dynamically loading Python application code from database under Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505357/dynamically-loading-python-application-code-from-database-under-google-app-engin)

Here is information on exec

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/exec.html

Python Wiki page for Python+MySQL

http://wiki.python.org/moin/MySQL

Comment: Thanks Russell! The first link looks promising to what I'm trying to accomplish.